# Mac OS X How to turn off 'ScopedBookmarkAgent wants to use "Local Items" keychain' message

Tags: macos, keychain

Message 'ScopedBookmarkAgent wants to use "Local Items" keychain.' appears every time I restart my laptop. How to turn it off? [image]

**How to solve the issue**

1. In the Finder click on the Go menu and select the 'Go to folder'
   option (⇧⌘G)
2. In the dialogue box type ~/Library/Keychains/ and click
   Enter [image]
3. Look for a folder with a name like this
   '0687DED4-EAE1-57DA-B27F-364FB153C9E5' and delete it (⇧⌘⌫)
4. Restart your Mac

Comment: Did you fix issue ?